# Pass state from one component to another

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass the date state from "Avaibalities.js" to "Modal.js". My date is showing when 2 dates are clicked in my Calendar. What i'm desperatly trying to do is when i validate my choice(date), i want my date to also appear on my Modal component.

Avaibalities.js

```
    class Avaibalities extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          date: new Date(),
          showDate: null,
          showModal: false
        };
      }
      onChange = date => {
        this.setState({
          date,
          showDate: true
        })
    
      };
    
      validation = () => {
        if (this.state.showDate) {
          this.setState({
            showDate: true,
            showModal: true
          });
        } else {
          alert('Please enter a valid date')
        }
      };
    
      reset = () => {
        this.setState({
          showDate: null
        })
      };
      dateToggle = date => {
        this.setState({
          date,
          showDate: true
        });
      }

/* render method with few jsx (I took some to not make my question too big, only keep the important)*/

<button className={'button'} onClick={this.validation}>Validate</button>

    {this.state.showDate
                    &&
                    <p>
                      From : {this.state.date[0].toLocaleDateString()} to :{' '}
                      {this.state.date[1].toLocaleDateString()}
                    </p>
                  }
 /*The dates are showed without problem below on my Avaibalities page */

    
    <h4>Please choose 2 dates and validate</h4>
    
    {this.state.showModal && <Modal toggle={this.togglePop} dateInModal={this.dateToggle} />}
    
/* Once a validate, my modal is showed*/
```

Here is the part where i'm blocked, i give a name on my calling Modal in my conditional method and trying to pass that data into my Modal component.

```
     Modal.js
        
        handleModal = () => {
            this.props.dateToggle();
          }
        
        <div><p>Your dates : {this.dateToggle}</p></div>
```

I hope i was enough specific.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass the entire state down to `Modal`

```
{this.state.showModal && <Modal state={this.state} toggle={this.togglePop} dateInModal={this.dateToggle} />}
```

We pass in a new prop called `state` in this case and you're passing your `state` down to your `Modal` component.

If you want to pass the date only

```
 {this.state.showModal && <Modal date={this.state.data} toggle={this.togglePop} dateInModal={this.dateToggle} />}
```

If you want to be more specific, you can even do `someRandomVariable = { state.date}`

Then in your `Modal` component, you will have that property available when you call `this.prop.state` or `this.prop.someRandomVariable`

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Crazy how simple it was!